# Whats the best way to return values in my Youtube Downloader .dll?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube

So I'm basically making a youtube downloader .dll. What I need is to return two different types of values with their own values. I have tried writing these to a temporary file but this is resource consuming.

I need to return a collection of values called the youtube links
I need to return a collection of values called the youtube link qualities
I need to return a collection of values called the youtube link types

How should I do this?
Dictionary?

Comment: Why do the `out` or `ref` specifiers not cover the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just defining a custom class which describes the returned data?

```
public class YouTubeLink
{
   int Quality{get;private set;}
   string Type{get;private set;};
   string Url{get;private set;};
   public YouTubeLink(...){...}
}

public class YouTubeVideoInfo
{
   public ReadOnlyCollection<YouTubeLink> Links{get;}
   ...
}
```